# How to create a category or tag available exclusively to the admins and not to the users?

Tags: categories, tags

I would like to create a category or tag name that is available only to the admin(s) and not to the authors.

For example, I would like to create a category or tag called `Exclusive Content`.

Now only admins should be able to add this category or tag to their posts. Other users should not be able to see it or use it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can restrict access to a tag with the following code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'remove_tags_function', 10, 2); 
function remove_tags_function( $post_id ){
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){ 
        $post_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'post_tag', array( 'fields'=>'names' ) );
        $pos = array_search( 'ExclusiveContent', $post_tags );
        if( false !== $pos ) {
            unset( $post_tags[$pos] );
            wp_set_post_terms ($post_id, $post_tags, 'post_tag');
        }
    }
}
```

So, with this code, whenever a normal user adds the tag `ExclusiveContent`, it will be removed upon save *unless* if the current user [can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) `manage_options`. This code should be added to your [functions.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file. You can find this file in your theme's folder.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you tell me where to put this code? :/

Comment: Absolutely, question updated.